# How to deal with spaces within paths when using the system()?

Tags: c++, system

I am still new to C++ and am working out a way to open a program within my C++ program.
The problem is that whenever I have spaces in my paths, it sees it as different parameters.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    system("C:\\Users\\blah\\Desktop\\a\\ b.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

The output I receive is:

```
'C:\Users\blah\Desktop\a\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can double quote your string literal. **Edit:** Also just noticed that your backslashes were not escaped so updated below :P

```
system("\"C:\\Users\\blah\\Desktop\\a\\ b.txt\"");
```

Also let it be known for the record that you really shouldn't use `system`.  Try fork, spawn, or perhaps even the unofficial boost.process class which has functionality similar to .NET process class depending on your needs.  Also think about why you need launch a process from a process ... perhaps you could make a library?

Answer (score 1):

On Unix, you could use fork() + exec().

On Windows, check out [spawn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

These execute the program directly, avoiding the command shell interpreter, thus avoiding any special treatment of special characters like spaces.